# Why is my rails helper file not recognizing my javascript methods?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have an `edit.haml.html` file that has a method call in it. The method call looks like this:

```
!= map_init('map', @account.latitude ? 7 : 0)
```

The `map_init` method is defined in a rails helper file `map_helper.rb`. The `map_init' function then chains off to a`map_script_load`and`map_js_initialization(id, zoom)` method defined like so:

```
def map_init(id, zoom = 2)
  map_script_load + map_js_initialization(id, zoom)
end

def map_script_load
  key = Rails.application.config.google_maps_api_key
  uri = "#{request.ssl? ? 'https' : 'http'}://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;key=#{key}"
  "<script src='#{uri}' type='text/javascript'></script>"
end 

 def map_js_initialization(id, zoom)
    javascript_tag <<-JSCRIPT
      $(document).ready(function() {
        Map.load('map', 25, 12, 2);
      });
    JSCRIPT
  end
```

The problem that I am having is that when my code gets to the `javascript_tag` within `map_js_initialization` the code breaks. A look into the console says that

`edit:1149 Uncaught TypeError: Map.load is not a function`

Of course, `Map.load` exists and is in my `map.js` file. On the console, I'm able to call this method directly and the map renders.

Why would it not be able to be called from a helper file. I suspect that this may be a scope issue. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this would fail? Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There's no "scoping" involved here. Check how it's actually rendering first and include that output here.

Comment: Hey Dave thanks for commenting so quickly. When you are asking out about the output of the how the page renders. Are you talking about out the output that Rails renders on localhost:3000 or maybe something on the Chrome development tools?

Comment: Check the raw html produced.